Location, GitHub, and Twitter links do not get copied over upon creating an account on a new site
When creating a profile after updating your location field, Twitter, and GitHub links on all profiles, they do not get copied over to the new account, though a website link (and everything else) does.
Steps to reproduce:

Edit your Location, Twitter, and GitHub fields to include anything legit.
Create a profile on a Stack Exchange account on which you hadn't been signed in before.
Notice the mentioned fields not appearing in your new profile.


Well, this combines two older bug reports, but it's all from same source and a fix will be for all of them, if and when it will be done.

They're different. My one is for creating new profiles, but your dupes are for just the all communities button.

Different symptom of same bug: the new profile process copy the profile in the same way as the "copy to all communities" as far as I can tell. If you can prove otherwise (e.g. a field that is updated in one but not the other), I'll happily reopen. :)

@ShadowWizard OK, let me test it now.

Okay, you win... I could've sworn yesterday it was different. :)
